# Category pages vs single post pages

Tags: posts, categories

For each of a few categories there is a "main" post which should be displayed at the top of the category list page. Should these pages (where both the "main" post and the list of the rest posts for a category are displayed) be category pages or single post pages (with a template)?

Also: Should I assign a post corresponding to category or category corresponding to a post?

Comment: I now think that using category pages should be preferred because this allows to add pagination if needed

Comment: ... But how to edit meta-data for a category (I need to specify the "main" post for a category)

Comment: save it in an option- I'm certain there's a question/answer on this site dealing with adding and saving extra category data in an option.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question right, you should try with category template and for the **"main"** post you can use [Sticky Post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts)